# Make connection with bluetooth on Mac os x

Tags: macos, bluetooth, serial-port

I have an rs-232 bluetooth adapter that I have connected to my mac.  The way that I am able to work with it is opening the /dev/tty.BT-123 at 115200 baud.  However I am unable to get it to connect to the device unless it is already connected.
Currently to get it to connect, I have been opening up system preferences, and clicking edit device to get it to connect.  After doing this I can get it to connect using the tty.

What I am looking for is a shell command or a C++ api to get it to connect before I open the tty.